# Named-pipe delivery confirmation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, named-pipes, mailslot

According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MailSlot)

"MailSlots offer no confirmation that a message has been received unless it is programmed into an application"

Do named-pipes offer this kind of confirmation?

(Any tips how it could be implemented in MailSlot would be also very appreciated)

Comment: No they don't. Pipes are just that, you pump the 'water' in and don't care what happens to it

Comment: You could take a look at TransactNamedPipe  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365790(v=vs.85).aspx